# Subset dataset with time condition in R

Tags: r, time, subset

I have a dataset like this in
example.txt

```
"09/Jan/2016" "05:00:22" "304" 449
"09/Jan/2016" "07:00:12" "304" 449
"09/Jan/2016" "10:00:02" "200" 10575
"09/Jan/2016" "11:00:03" "304" 449
"09/Jan/2016" "13:00:03" "304" 449
"09/Jan/2016" "20:00:03" "304" 449 
"09/Jan/2016" "23:00:03" "304" 450 
"10/Jan/2016" "00:00:03" "304" 449 
"10/Jan/2016" "03:00:03" "304" 449 
"10/Jan/2016" "04:00:03" "304" 449
```

Can I subset my dataset from range six hour before I run my code in R?
For example, I open and run my code in January 10th, at 4:15, so I want subset from my dataset, like

```
"09/Jan/2016" "23:00:03" "304" 450 
"10/Jan/2016" "00:00:03" "304" 449 
"10/Jan/2016" "03:00:03" "304" 449 
"10/Jan/2016" "04:00:03" "304" 449
```

what function should I use for my question? and how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the 4 columns which you have , have names `V1`, `V2`, `V3` and `V4` and the dataframe is `df`

You can do this in `base R` by

```
mergedDateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$V1, df$V2), format = "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df[(Sys.time() - 6*60*60) <  mergedDateTime & Sys.time() > mergedDateTime, ]
```

For the given example this would work as,

```
x <- "01/10/2016 04:15:00"
mergedDateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$V1, df$V2), format = "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df[(as.POSIXct(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") - 6*60*60) <  mergedDateTime & 
                as.POSIXct(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") > mergedDateTime, ]


#        V1       V2      V3  V4
#7  09/Jan/2016 23:00:03 304 450
#8  10/Jan/2016 00:00:03 304 449
#9  10/Jan/2016 03:00:03 304 449
#10 10/Jan/2016 04:00:03 304 449
```

Answer (score 2):

The [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) and [chron](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chron/index.html) packages, when used in conjunction, are very powerful and expressive for working with dates and times:

```
library(readr)
library(chron)
library(lubridate)

# read the data in
df_foo = read_table(file = '"09/Jan/2016" "05:00:22" "304" 449
"09/Jan/2016" "07:00:12" "304" 449
"09/Jan/2016" "10:00:02" "200" 10575
"09/Jan/2016" "11:00:03" "304" 449
"09/Jan/2016" "13:00:03" "304" 449
"09/Jan/2016" "20:00:03" "304" 449 
"09/Jan/2016" "23:00:03" "304" 450 
"10/Jan/2016" "00:00:03" "304" 449 
"10/Jan/2016" "03:00:03" "304" 449 
"10/Jan/2016" "04:00:03" "304" 449', 
                    col_names = c("Date", "Time", "Value1", "Value2"))

# parse dates and times
df_foo = df_foo %>% 
  mutate(
    # parse the dates
    Date = as.Date(gsub('"', "", Date), format = "%d/%b/%Y"),
    # parse the times
    Time = times(format(gsub('"', "", Time), format = "%H:%M:%S")),
    Value1 = as.integer(gsub('"', "", Value1)),
    # datetime
    Datetime = ISOdatetime(
      month = month(Date), 
      day = days(Date), 
      hour = hours(Time),
      sec = seconds(Time),
      min = minutes(Time),
      year = year(Date)
    )
  )

# filter to data within 6 hours of the current time
df_foo %>% 
  filter(
    Datetime > Sys.time() - dhours(6)
  )
```

Obviously, given the data sample you have included in the question, this returns nothing.

Comment: This could be done a lot simpler in lubridate - `parse_date_time(paste(df_foo$Date, df_foo$Time), orders="dmyHMS")` for instance or even in base R it is only one line - `as.POSIXct(paste(df_foo$Date, df_foo$Time), format="%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")`

Comment: @thelatemail You are referring to the datetime construction? My version is also one call to `ISOdatetime`. Unable to see the economies in either of your versions.